# Check User Coordinates first and then Enable Features

Tags: ios, mapkit, coordinates

In my project, I need to check user coordinates. If user lives in US, then I will enable a feature which shows air quality. Then further if user lives in Houston and surrounding area, then I will enable another feature which shows another feature, Ozone value. How could I achieve that? I could detect Houston and surrounding area with the following code, but I do not know how to find apart US states from Houston and World.

```
if((currentLocation.latitude>=28.930661 && currentLocation.latitude<=30.443953 && currentLocation.longitude>=-95.899668 && currentLocation.longitude<=-94.690486) ||
        currentLocation.longitude == 0 || currentLocation.latitude == 0) {

        // It is in the bounds

        [self.opponentAvatarImageView removeFromSuperview];

        UIActionSheet *actionsheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Would you like to see ozone cloud in your area or a trace of your walking/driving/biking activity" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OzoneMap", @"TraceMap", nil];

        [actionsheet showInView:self.view];

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the CLGeocoder class to pass in your location (CLLocation) and have it reverse geocode an address for you. You could even get specific with the City as well.

```
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:
    ^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
        CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks firstObject];
        if ([placemark.country isEqualToString:@"United States"]) {
             // You're in the U.S.
        }
}];
```